# Problem uploading Excel-document. What's wrong?

Tags: apache-flex, excel

For some reason, not all of Excel-documents can be upload from my computer. In half the cases get the error ".. no!! error:" from a block of try-catch .. What is wrong?

```
        private function importXLS(e:MouseEvent):void {
            fr = new FileReference();
            var fileFilter:FileFilter = new FileFilter("Excel (.xls)", "*.xls");
            fr.addEventListener(Event.SELECT,selectXLS);
            fr.browse([fileFilter]);
            statusLabel.text = "selecting...";
        }

        private function selectXLS(e:Event):void {
            fr = FileReference(e.target);
            fr.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, fileIn);
            fr.load();
            statusLabel.text = "loading...";
        }

        private function fileIn(e:Event):void {
            ba = new ByteArray();
            ba = fr.data;

            xls = new ExcelFile();

            var flag:Boolean = false;
            try{
                xls.loadFromByteArray(ba);
                flag = true;
            }catch(error:Error){
                Alert.show("no!! error: " + error.getStackTrace());
            }
            if (flag == true) {
                statusLabel.text = "XlS loaded.";
            } else {
                statusLabel.text = "XlS didn't load.";
            }

        }
```

Comment: Possibly because a lot of people consider that a csv file or a file containing HTML markup are automagically converted to an Excel file if they are given an extension of .xls. Try checking the actual content of those files that fail to see if they really are Excel files, or something else masquerading as an excel file.

Comment: I've created the files, or them create my friends.They really are Excel files

Comment: What're the contents of error.getStackTrace(), should give the suspect line number in the loadFromByteArray and any subsequent method calls, what happens when you run in debug mode and it hits this error, does ba look like it has the correct value (some sort of byte array with length).  Need more debugging info.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading the entire file into memory.  If a user tries to upload too big a file, their browser will crash.  Is there a reason you doing this?  Are you using the bytes in the client or just passing them to the server.  If you are passing them to the server, you want to just not use the fr.load method that you call in selectXLS().  Instead use fr.upload and avoid your whole problem.